# Notice: Array to string conversion PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am finding the intersection between two arrays `$item` and `$query` respectively:

`Array ( [0] => twitter [1] => 1 [2] => 561522539340771328 [3] => Array ( ) )`

`Array ( [0] => dig [1] => twitter )`

This is the code I have:

```
if (array_intersect ( $query, $item )) {
            $intersection [] = $item;
}
```

Somehow it's returning the notice as defined on the title of this question. Either I'm too tired to notice what's wrong or I may be going mad, **shouldn't it return** `Array ( [0] => twitter )`**?**

Comment: This is because of your empty array at the end of your first array, remove it and it should work fine, does that do the trick for you or can't you change the array? (BTW: Now you just asign the `$item` array to `$intersection`, but i think you want to assign the output of `array_intersect` to a variable which you then can use)

Comment: Well technically, I can't remove it as that array may contain a list of extracted locations, however I'll just modify it to be set to 0 if no locations are found. Thank you!

Actually the `$item` assignment in `$intersection` is intended!

Comment: Wrote a answer, If you have a multidimensional array you can use [`array_uintersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-uintersect.php) to compare the values.

Answer (score 3):

This is because you have an empty array at the end of your first array and [`array_intersect()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) is going to try to convert it to a string which gives you this error.

But to get rid of this error you can use [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like this:

(Also you want to assign the output of array_intersect and then use this)

```
<?php       

    $item = array("twitter", 1, 561522539340771328, array());
    $query = array("dig", "twitter");

    if ($intersect = array_intersect($query, array_filter($item))) {
                                           //^^^^^^^^^^^^ See here
        $intersection [] = $intersect;
    }

    print_r($intersection);

?>
```

Output:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => twitter ) )
```

Comment: I tried this but it still would not work as the array wouldn't always be empty since it may contain locations sometimes. I was not aware that it was due to the final element being an array though so thanks. I've found a solution, posting shortly!